Spring Data Rest Project is returning embedded object which I couldn't utilize with webflux
I have a Spring Data REST project running in my local in the same local I am also running spring webflux project connects to REST project when I run api which calls getallentities its returning object with null values even though database has some data in table. indicidual /{id} calls working find but getallentities call is returning data wrongly the rest returns data in form of embedded and href object. can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here?
Spring Data REST response:

Spring WebFlux Response for the above api

Codeblock that pulls data from Data Rest app

